# Memory cost of sending items over mpsc channel

Tags: rust

I have two threads that read a stream of messages from two sources and then forward them to a third sink where they get processed in order.

I'm concerned about the overhead of copying data as my messages are on each thread's stack and to move them through `mpsc`, every bit has to be copied over to the sink's stack.

If I try to mitigate this by putting my message in a `Box`, then only the pointer would be sent over to the new stack but still a copy happens from source's stack to heap.

And I'm not entirely sure if my message is on heap or stack, as I saw a blog post in rust-lang.org the other day which claimed a `vec![1,2,3]` lives on stack, which if true, is something I wouldn't have guessed.

Comment: "I saw a blog post in rust-lang.org the other day which claimed a `vec![1,2,3]` lives on stack" - `Vec` itself, i.e. triple "pointer + size + capacity", lives on stack, but the data it contains, i.e. sequence `1, 2, 3`, lives on heap.

Comment: It sounds like there are two questions here: 1. what's the time it takes to copy some data from one thread's stack to anther and, from your last paragraph, 2. how much of your message is on the stack and how much is on the heap.  To help with the second question: could you post more details on the structure of the message itself?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar concerns and didn't find satisfying answers, but I have some logic that can help with concerns.

With regards to overheads, using the MPSR channel is the recommended way to do concurrency in Rust (with message passing being promoted as a safety feature, less error-prone than direct sharing using Arc pointers and Mutexes). While we can expect it to have some overhead costs, we can also trust that the Rust team is recommending it for a reason as the standard way to do multi-threading - and they value speed. In all likelihood, the overhead is very low and I suspect that under the hood you are only changing ownership (because on a hardware level all threads have access to the same memory in ways that multiple processes don't).

So basically, Rust uses smart pointers for multiprocessing and the only thing that really needs to change when passing a message is ownership of the pointers, and thus the underlying data on the heap.

Big however: I found a crate called "bus" which is a single-producer multiple-consumer system that someone based off of the MPSC code. It has a known problem for high CPU usage (https://github.com/jonhoo/bus/issues/23). I didn't find anything like that for MPSC, but I did find a complaint about memory (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/mpsc-channels-high-memory-usage/78651/5). Having read the replies though, I don't think this is an issue you need to worry about.